# Invoice Balance per row

Tags: sql, oracle

Please see code below and results and expected results

```
 SELECT 
    DISTINCT VW_PM_INV_BAL.invoice_no,                      
    VW_PM_INV_BAL.quote_section_id , 
    paymatic_debtors_info.type, 
    cl$invoices.total INVOICED_AMT, 
    paymatic_debtors_info.amount PAID_CR_REV 
 FROM 
    paymatic_debtors_info 
 left outer JOIN cl$invoices 
    ON cl$invoices.invoice_no = paymatic_debtors_info.ref 
 left outer JOIN VW_PM_INV_BAL 
    ON VW_PM_INV_BAL.invoice_no = cl$invoices.invoice_no 
 WHERE 
   VW_PM_INV_BAL.quote_section_id = '1000065052' 
 ORDER BY 1, 2 DESC;
```

Results

```
Invoice_no  Quote_section_id   Type   Invoiced   Paid_CR_REV 
729001      1000065052         Inv      70680       70680 
729001      1000065052         Pmt      70680      -70680 
732331      1000065052         Inv      21556.26    21556.26 
732331      1000065052         Pmt      21556.26   -21556.26 
751231      1000065052         Inv      21556.374   21556.37 
751231      1000065052         Pmt      21556.374   -21556.37 
753107      1000065052         Inv      21556.374   21556.37 
753107      1000065052         Pmt      21556.374   -21556.37 
753107      1000065052         Rev      21556.374   21556.37
```

Expected

```
Invoice_no   Quote_section_id Type Invoiced Paid_CR_REV Balance 
729001       1000065052       Inv   70680
729001       1000065052       Pmt           -70680           0 
732331       1000065052       Inv   21556.26
732331       1000065052       Pmt           -21556.26        0 
751231       1000065052       Inv   21556.374
751231       1000065052       Pmt           -21556.37        0 
753107       1000065052       Inv   21556.374
753107       1000065052       Pmt           -21556.37        0 
753107       1000065052       Rev   21556.374                21556.374
```

Comment: Please edit your question properly.

Comment: please highlight the differencies between the actual and expected results. formatting is also needed

Comment: When LEFT JOIN, put the right side table's conditions in the ON clause to get true left join behavior. (When in WHERE, you get regular inner join result.)

Comment: The WHERE clause is just to get that set of records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,

- for an 'Inv' row you want to show Invoiced, but neither Paid_CR_REV nor Balance.
- for a 'Pmt' row you want to show Paid_CR_REV and Invoiced + Paid_CR_REV as Balance, but not Invoiced.
- for a 'Rev' row you want to show Invoiced twice, once as Invoiced, once as Balance and no Paid_CR_REV.

Use `CASE WHEN` accordingly:

```
select
  bal.invoice_no,
  bal.quote_section_id ,
  pdi.type,
  case when pdi.type in ('Inv', 'Rev') then inv.total end as invoiced,
  case when pdi.type = 'Pmt' then pdi.amount end as paid_cr_rev,
  case when pdi.type = 'Pmt' then inv.total + pdi.amount
       when pdi.type = 'Rev' then inv.total end as balance
from paymatic_debtors_info pdi
join cl$invoices inv on inv.invoice_no = pdi.ref
join vw_pm_inv_bal bal on bal.invoice_no = inv.invoice_no
where bal.quote_section_id = '1000065052'
order by 1, 2 desc;
```

At least this is what I gather from what you are showing. You were not really asking a question and didn't tell us anything about your tables and how to compute the results. So you may still have to adjust above query a little.

I don't think you need `DISTINCT` here, so I removed it. Put it back if you do need it. (Or rewrite the query such that you don't.)

I don't think you need outer joins either (in your shown results at least all records are always present), so I removed these, too.

Comment: Nope its complaining about line 5

Comment: So when told the line, are you still not able to spot the mistake? I simply forgot to remove your column alias names, that's all. The fact that you are not able yet to spot such simple typos plus a dubious DISTINCT and improper outer joins make me think you should start with simpler queries and practise with them first. Learn SQL step by step.